# How to detect browser version in Angular 4 in order to prevent usage in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browser

Is there a way in Angular 4 (typescript) that can help detect browser type?

I am using Angular 4 and would like to know how I can figure out the browser type when my application loads. I basically do not want my application to load when someone uses IE and alternatively show a message that they need to use chrome or firefox instead.

I have tried solving this issue by using the below libraries, but they have issues or are for older angular versions:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js - This library is supported for angular 1.x, however, I am on Angular 4.
- https://github.com/KoderLabs/ng2-device-detector - Has issues when launching in IE, so does not work as expected.

What are some alternative ways of detecting browser type, be that code or a suitable library, in Angular 4 or directly using typescript?

Answer (score 2):

pls check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-responsive

You can show/hide component based on browser type. I hope it helps.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
template: '
   <p *isChrome>I'll show you if I'm a Chrome Browser.</p>
   <p *isFirefox>I'll show you if I'm a Firefox Browser.</p>
   <p *isSafari>I'll show you if I'm a Safari Browser.</p>
   <p *isOpera>I'll show you if I'm a Opera Browser.</p>
   <p *isIE>I'll show you if I'm a Internet Explorer Browser.</p>
'
})
```

Comment: pls let me know if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Erica asked for a way to hide information when IE was used. How do you invert `*isIE` to not show an element?